# What is the best index for INNER JOINs having a WHERE and an ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join, where-clause

I'm using MySQL and InnoDB.
Suppose that I've the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM
Foo
INNER JOIN
Bar
ON Foo.id = Bar.fooId
WHERE Foo.column1 = N
ORDER BY Foo.column2 DESC LIMIT 100
```

Here, `Foo.id` is the primary key and `Bar.fooId` is the FK.

What's the best index I should add to `Foo` and `Bar` tables?

Currently I've an index on `(Foo.column1, Foo.column2)` in `Foo` table. Should I add `Foo.id` to this composite index too? What's the order?

I couldn't find any formal reference to cover this subject.

Comment: Hope that Foo.id is primary key & Bar.fooId is foreign key. right?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Yes. Edited.

Comment: NO need to add foo.id as composite index.It is sufficient.

Comment: Is the selected `id` the `Foo.id` or a `Bar.id`?

Comment: It depends.  The answer for that one `SELECT` won't necessarily be 'right' for another `SELECT`.  [More tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 0):

`(Foo.column1, Foo.column2)` should be sufficient for `Foo`, you don't need to add the PK to the end because innodb always has the PK at the end of every index.
`Bar` needs to have an index on `fooId`.

Run `explain <query>` to check what MySQL is doing.

For `Foo` you should get type `ref`, `using index` in the extra without `using filesort` and 100 rows.

`Bar` should have type `ref` and `using index` in the extra.